# Removing specific html tags in perl

Tags: perl

I Have a html file stored on the disk(The file is [This](http://home.howstuffworks.com/home-improvement/construction/projects/return-on-investment-from-remodel2.htm)) . I want to remove all the html tags of images. This is what i have tried so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use HTML::TagFilter;
my $tf = new HTML::TagFilter;

open READ, "D:\\Scripts\\file.html" or die "Couldn't open file: $!"; 
$string1 = join("", <READ>); 
close READ;

my $self = HTML::TagFilter->new(deny => {img => {'all'}});
open (MYFILE, '>D:\\Scripts\\remove.html');
print MYFILE $tf->filter($string1);
close (MYFILE);
```

If i just run this program it prints

```
Odd number of elements in anonymous hash at remove everything else.pl line 9.
Parsing of undecoded UTF-8 will give garbage when decoding entities at C:/Perl64
/site/lib/HTML/TagFilter.pm line 499.
```

The file is stored but it does not have the image tags removed(The line 9 is where i apply the filter). What am i doing wrong here.

Comment: The error says it all: `{'all'}` has an odd number of elements, and thus isn't a valid hash. Replace it with `'all'`, `{'all' => 'somevalue'}` or `['all']` depending on whether it's supposed to be a scalar, hash or array.

Comment: And add `use strict;` to your script. You'll benefit from it in the long run.

Comment: Yes. That works. But the ads are still displayed. Any idea how to remove them. Also how would i just get content on that page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of your program, especially before asking for help to fix it.

You have created two `HTML::TagFilter` objects: `$tf` which has no filters and `$self` which removes `<img>` elements. You have used `$tf` to process the HTML so your data is unchanged.

This code works, with the corrections I have mentioned and a couple of others.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TagFilter;

my $tf = HTML::TagFilter->new(deny => {img => {all => []}});

my $html = do {
  open my $fh, 'D:\Scripts\file.html' or die "Couldn't open file: $!";
  local $/;
  <$fh>;
};

open my $out, '>', 'D:\Scripts\remove.html' or die "Unable to open output file: $!";
print $out $tf->filter($html);
```

Comment: He is using warnings as suggested by the warnings included in the question. I'll agree that `use warnings` is better practice than the `w` flag for anything other than a shell one-liner though.

Comment: Just that it looked like you were implying that he wasn't, and it's the use of `warnings` which produces the output he's asking for help with (even if that isn't his only problem).

Comment: OK, sorry if that wasn't clear.  I'm astonished so many people still use -w when it is pretty much irrelevant to anything but Unix systems

Comment: That works but do you have an idea how to remove the ads because some images are still retained.

Comment: Some of the ads are background-images, like `html#type-toyota-article-structured.template-toyota-article body a div#brandscape`. That's why you cannot remove them with this. There are also some flash elements I believe.

Comment: So there is no way to remove them is there.